# J8 Stream Sorting by Vector in List<Tuple2<Vector, String>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Tuple2<Vector, String>> vectors = parsedData1.collect();

vectors.stream().map(e -> e._2 + " : " + clusters.predict(e._1)).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The above code creates a list of results that attaches an int to a string. When I go to print them I get something like this:

[image]

How do I sort the stream by the number and not the string?

Comment: you can sort before you map as well `vectors.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> clusters.predict(e._1)))
                .map(e -> e._2 + " : " + clusters.predict(e._1))
                .forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: But depending on what `clusters.predict(e._1)` does, you might want avoid the overhead of calling it multiple times for the same item. So `map` to an object holding the string and the result of `clusters.predict(e._1)`, `sort` by the latter, `map` to the result string, and print the strings.

Comment: Also can I ask Naman, even though your solution is valid and works perfectly, why would that same solution not work for a parallelStream() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `sorted(Comparator)` that enables sorting based on a custom comparing mechanism. Another thing you want is to sort first *before* you concatenate the String, otherwise, you would need to split it back to detect a number, sort based according to it, and concatenate again.

```
vectors.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> clusters.predict(e._1)))
       .map(e -> e._2 + " : " + clusters.predict(e._1))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

In case `clusters.predict(e._1)` is computationally expensive, you might want to precompute its value and act then:

```
vectors.stream()
       .map(e -> new Tuple2<>(clusters.predict(e._1), e._2))
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e._1))
       .map(e -> e._2 + " : " + e._1)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Great thanks Nikolas I'll keep the computational cost in mind next time too!